# Matlab not reading Romanian fonts in text-to-speech engine

Tags: matlab, text-to-speech, sapi

I am using Matlab bridge to the Windows text-to-speech engine with the function below and the Ivona Romanian voice Carmen. However, the code will not read at all the special Romanian characters, such as ș, ț, ǎ, etc. The words with these special characters are read by TextAlound on the same computer.

For instance, if I have: txt = 'șapcǎ' and voice = 'IVONA 2 Carmen OEM - Romanian female voice [22kHz]' and fs = 14400 the phonemes for ș and ǎ are not read.

```
function wav = tts(txt,voice,pace,fs)
%TTS text to speech.
%   TTS (TXT) synthesizes speech from string TXT, and speaks it. The audio
%   format is mono, 16 bit, 16k Hz by default.
%   
%   WAV = TTS(TXT) does not vocalize but output to the variable WAV.
%
%   TTS(TXT,VOICE) uses the specific voice. Use TTS('','List') to see a
%   list of availble voices. Default is the first voice.
%
%   TTS(...,PACE) set the pace of speech to PACE. PACE ranges from 
%   -10 (slowest) to 10 (fastest). Default 0.
%
%   TTS(...,FS) set the sampling rate of the speech to FS kHz. FS must be
%   one of the following: 8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000,
%       44100, 48000. Default 16.
%   
%   This function requires the Microsoft Win32 Speech API (SAPI).
%
%   Examples:
%       % Speak the text;
%       tts('I can speak.');
%       % List availble voices;
%       tts('I can speak.','List');
%       % Do not speak out, store the speech in a variable;
%       w = tts('I can speak.',[],-4,44100);
%       wavplay(w,44100);
%
%   See also WAVREAD, WAVWRITE, WAVPLAY.

% Written by Siyi Deng; 12-21-2007;

if ~ispc, error('Microsoft Win32 SAPI is required.'); end
if ~ischar(txt), error('First input must be string.'); end

SV = actxserver('SAPI.SpVoice');
TK = invoke(SV,'GetVoices');

if nargin > 1
    % Select voice;
    for k = 0:TK.Count-1
        if strcmpi(voice,TK.Item(k).GetDescription)
            SV.Voice = TK.Item(k);
            break;
        elseif strcmpi(voice,'list')
            disp(TK.Item(k).GetDescription);
        end
    end
    % Set pace;
    if nargin > 2
        if isempty(pace), pace = 0; end
        if abs(pace) > 10, pace = sign(pace)*10; end        
        SV.Rate = pace;
    end
end

if nargin < 4 || ~ismember(fs,[8000,11025,12000,16000,22050,24000,32000,...
        44100,48000]), fs = 16000; end

if nargout > 0
   % Output variable;
   MS = actxserver('SAPI.SpMemoryStream');
   MS.Format.Type = sprintf('SAFT%dkHz16BitMono',fix(fs/1000));
   SV.AudioOutputStream = MS;  
end

invoke(SV,'Speak',txt);

if nargout > 0
    % Convert uint8 to double precision;
    wav = reshape(double(invoke(MS,'GetData')),2,[])';
    wav = (wav(:,2)*256+wav(:,1))/32768;
    wav(wav >= 1) = wav(wav >= 1)-2;
    delete(MS);
    clear MS;
end

delete(SV); 
clear SV TK;
pause(0.2);

end % TTS;
```

Comment: Do you have to use Windows?  In other words what's wrong with using TextAloud?  Also have you checked that the computer's (Windows) language and region are set to Romanian?

Comment: I changed the region to Romanian but does not help. I need to use Windows as I do this in a large program, mixing thousands of words in different languages.

Comment: I managed to solve it. The code is below: 

    % change character set
    feature('DefaultCharacterSet','ISO-8859-2');
    
    % start synthetiser
    NET.addAssembly('System.Speech');
    
    % star object
    Speaker = System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer;

    % set output to wav file
    Speaker.SetOutputToWaveFile('temp.wav');

    % speak test
    Speaker.Speak(txt);
    
    % dispose
    Speaker.Dispose;

Comment: @Claude you should make this an official answer.